# jQuery code integration

Tags: jquery, html, integration

I have some jQuery code which works how I want but I am finding it difficult to integrate this code into another file I am working on. Here is the code which I have:

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ausp02ot/)

Hopefully you will see from the above link what I am trying to achieve. I need to integrate this into the below code but so far have only managed to permintenly fix the blocked date 3 days after the current date. I am using the same HTML as the jsfiddle so I need to just integrate the jQuery into the following code:

```
    function tm_set_datepicker(){
    if (!$.datepicker){
        return;
    }

    var inputIds = $('input').map(function() {
        return this.id;
    }).get().join(' ');

    var update_date_fields = function(input, inst){
        var id = $(input).attr("id"),
            day = $('#' + id + '_day'),
            month = $('#' + id + '_month'),
            year = $('#' + id + '_year');

        day.val(inst.selectedDay);
        month.val(inst.selectedMonth + 1);
        year.val(inst.selectedYear);
    };

    $( ".tm-epo-datepicker" ).each(function(i,el){
        var startDate=parseInt($(this).attr('data-start-year')),
            endDate=parseInt($(this).attr('data-end-year')),
            format=$(this).attr('data-date-format'),
            show=$(this).attr('data-date-showon');

        $(el).datepicker({
            monthNames: tm_epo_js.monthNames,
            monthNamesShort: tm_epo_js.monthNamesShort,
            dayNames: tm_epo_js.dayNames,
            dayNamesShort: tm_epo_js.dayNamesShort,
            dayNamesMin: tm_epo_js.dayNamesMin,
            isRTL: tm_epo_js.isRTL,

            showOn: show,
            buttonText:"",
            showButtonPanel: true,
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            dateFormat: format,
            minDate: 3,
            maxDate: new Date(endDate, 12 - 1, 31),
            onSelect: function (dateText, inst) {
               update_date_fields(this, inst);
            },
            beforeShow: function(input, inst) {
                $('#ui-datepicker-div').removeClass(inputIds);
                $('#ui-datepicker-div').addClass(this.id+ ' tm-epo-skin');
                $("body").addClass("tm-static");
                $(el).prop("readonly",true);
            },
            onClose: function(dateText, inst) {
                $("body").removeClass("tm-static");
                $(el).trigger("change");
                $(el).prop("readonly",false);
            }
        }).on('change.tmdate', function(e){
            var id='#' + $(this).attr("id"),
                input=$(this),
                format=input.attr('data-date-format'),
                date = input.datepicker('getDate'),
                day='',month='',year='',
                day_field=$(id + '_day'),
                month_field=$(id + '_month'),
                year_field=$(id + '_year');

            if (date){
                day  = date.getDate();
                month = date.getMonth() + 1;
                year =  date.getFullYear();
            }
            day_field.val(day);
            month_field.val(month);
            year_field.val(year);

        });
    });

    $('.tmcp-date-select').on('change.cpf',function(e){
        var id='#' + $(this).attr("data-tm-date"),
            input=$(id),
            format=input.attr('data-date-format'),
            day=$(id + '_day').val(),
            month=$(id + '_month').val(),
            year=$(id + '_year').val(),
            dateFormat = $.datepicker.formatDate(format, new Date( year, month-1, day));
        if (day>0 && month>0 && year>0){
            input.datepicker( "setDate", dateFormat );
            input.trigger("change");
        }else{
            input.val("");
            input.trigger("change.cpf");
        }            
    });       

    $(window).on("resizestart",function() {            
        var field = $(document.activeElement);
        if (field.is('.hasDatepicker')) {
            field.data("resizestarted",true);
            if ($(window).width()<768){
                field.data("resizewidth",true);
                return;
            }
            field.datepicker('hide');                
        }
    });
    $(window).on("resizestop",function() {            
        var field = $(document.activeElement);
        if (field.is('.hasDatepicker') && field.data("resizestarted")) {
            if (field.data("resizewidth")){
                field.datepicker('hide');
            }
            field.datepicker('show');                
        }
        field.data("resizestarted",false);
        field.data("resizewidth",false);
    });

};
```

Any help would be very much appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

You have to call this code when your document is loaded, like below. JSFiddle does that for you on the fly but in your own project you have to wrap your code inside the `$(document).ready()` block. 
Also make sure you have linked to jQuery in your `<head>` section.

```
$(document).ready( function() {    

function tm_set_datepicker(){
    if (!$.datepicker){
        return;
    }

    var inputIds = $('input').map(function() {
        return this.id;
    }).get().join(' ');

    var update_date_fields = function(input, inst){
        var id = $(input).attr("id"),
            day = $('#' + id + '_day'),
            month = $('#' + id + '_month'),
            year = $('#' + id + '_year');

        day.val(inst.selectedDay);
        month.val(inst.selectedMonth + 1);
        year.val(inst.selectedYear);
    };

    $( ".tm-epo-datepicker" ).each(function(i,el){
        var startDate=parseInt($(this).attr('data-start-year')),
            endDate=parseInt($(this).attr('data-end-year')),
            format=$(this).attr('data-date-format'),
            show=$(this).attr('data-date-showon');

        $(el).datepicker({
            monthNames: tm_epo_js.monthNames,
            monthNamesShort: tm_epo_js.monthNamesShort,
            dayNames: tm_epo_js.dayNames,
            dayNamesShort: tm_epo_js.dayNamesShort,
            dayNamesMin: tm_epo_js.dayNamesMin,
            isRTL: tm_epo_js.isRTL,

            showOn: show,
            buttonText:"",
            showButtonPanel: true,
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            dateFormat: format,
            minDate: 3,
            maxDate: new Date(endDate, 12 - 1, 31),
            onSelect: function (dateText, inst) {
               update_date_fields(this, inst);
            },
            beforeShow: function(input, inst) {
                $('#ui-datepicker-div').removeClass(inputIds);
                $('#ui-datepicker-div').addClass(this.id+ ' tm-epo-skin');
                $("body").addClass("tm-static");
                $(el).prop("readonly",true);
            },
            onClose: function(dateText, inst) {
                $("body").removeClass("tm-static");
                $(el).trigger("change");
                $(el).prop("readonly",false);
            }
        }).on('change.tmdate', function(e){
            var id='#' + $(this).attr("id"),
                input=$(this),
                format=input.attr('data-date-format'),
                date = input.datepicker('getDate'),
                day='',month='',year='',
                day_field=$(id + '_day'),
                month_field=$(id + '_month'),
                year_field=$(id + '_year');

            if (date){
                day  = date.getDate();
                month = date.getMonth() + 1;
                year =  date.getFullYear();
            }
            day_field.val(day);
            month_field.val(month);
            year_field.val(year);

        });
    });

    $('.tmcp-date-select').on('change.cpf',function(e){
        var id='#' + $(this).attr("data-tm-date"),
            input=$(id),
            format=input.attr('data-date-format'),
            day=$(id + '_day').val(),
            month=$(id + '_month').val(),
            year=$(id + '_year').val(),
            dateFormat = $.datepicker.formatDate(format, new Date( year, month-1, day));
        if (day>0 && month>0 && year>0){
            input.datepicker( "setDate", dateFormat );
            input.trigger("change");
        }else{
            input.val("");
            input.trigger("change.cpf");
        }            
    });       

    $(window).on("resizestart",function() {            
        var field = $(document.activeElement);
        if (field.is('.hasDatepicker')) {
            field.data("resizestarted",true);
            if ($(window).width()<768){
                field.data("resizewidth",true);
                return;
            }
            field.datepicker('hide');                
        }
    });
    $(window).on("resizestop",function() {            
        var field = $(document.activeElement);
        if (field.is('.hasDatepicker') && field.data("resizestarted")) {
            if (field.data("resizewidth")){
                field.datepicker('hide');
            }
            field.datepicker('show');                
        }
        field.data("resizestarted",false);
        field.data("resizewidth",false);
    });

};
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, I actually need help with the jQuery code itself. I need to alter the code above to include the same functionality as the jsfiddle code. I need it to be able to toggle the blocked dates depending on which radio button is selected.